# Puppeteer with Node 10.5.0 multi thread

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Am I able to use multi thread with Puppeteer for parallel testing?

Answer (score 2):

I answered your question here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2799#issuecomment-400430516